# best moving background estimation method and detection

Tags: opencv, background, detection

I would like to discuss the best method to make a moving background estimation method and detect a new object entering in the FOV of the camera.
My stereo camera is actually moving along an axis, and it is supposed to detect if someone is within a specific range. 
I am wondering how I could detect a new object entering in the FOV of the camera,
shall I pre-record images of the empty space and then compare the frames to the currents and do some kind of subtraction?

To detect people in a specific range, I would generate a point cloud thanks to the stereo camera and then calculate the distance.

Could please advise me on this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just as a hint: Have you had a look at optical flow algorithms? Maybe with that, you could distinguish objects that move with a different speed than the background.

Comment: but to consider something as the background, I would have to pre record it right?

Comment: to consider something as the background you must either have information about how the background looks like (maybe no optical flow needed, but can be used to find the background movement) or you can try to estimate "things" that move inside the image according to the camera-movement in contrast to "things" that move inside the image against camera-movement (but you can only detect moving objects in that way). You won't be able to detect static foreground objects without knowing how your background looks like!